# Parity signer issue

Tags: parity, parity-wallet, offline, parity-signer

I'm trying to send raw transactions throught JSON-RPC api. I'm signing it offline (with python lib) and then using the eth_sendRawTransaction method.

The thing is that sometimes it gets broadcasted successfully, but sometimes it ends stucked in the Signer tab, Local transactions section (in the Parity build in wallet) and the tx is never broadcasted.

What can be happening?

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Parity/v1.6.8-beta-c396229-20170608/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.17.0

Comment: This might be a bug and you should probably open an issue on GitHub to get support.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the interface with `--no-ui`?